# Proof that every ultrametric space is a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, ultrametric

Can anyone help me, how to prove in general, that that every ultrametric space is a metric space?

Comment: Begin by writing down the two definitions.  Check the properties required one by one.  Write in your question what happened and where you got stuck.

Comment: @GEdgar I had a problem to show that the triangle inequality, but now I got it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\max \{a, b\} \leq a+b$ for any $a,b \geq 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much